# Angular TypeScript: "Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'."

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm coding along with the book *Pro Angular 9*, by Adam Freeman. Line 8 is throwing an error:

```js
private categories: string[] = [];
```

The error is

```
Error: src/app/model/product.repository.ts:13:7 - error TS2322:
Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I have no idea what that line means. How can a variable be a string and an array?

To confuse me further, Angular says the error is in line 13, not line 8. Here's line 13:

```js
this.categories = data.map(p => p.category).filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
```

I don't know what that line does, other than run a map over an array with a filter.

The file has two more errors. Line 17:

```js
getProducts(category: string = null): Product[] {
```

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

In JavaScript I would make an empty string: `var myString = ''`. In TypeScript why would you make a string null? Aren't `string` and `null` different types?

The third error is in line 22:

```js
return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
```

```
Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
```

I have no idea what that means.

Here's the entire file:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { StaticDataSource } from "./static.datasource";

@Injectable()
export class ProductRepository {
  private products: Product[] = [];
  private categories: string[] = [];

  constructor(private dataSource: StaticDataSource) {
    dataSource.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
      this.categories = data.map(p => p.category).filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
    });
  }

  getProducts(category: string = null): Product[] {
    return this.products.filter(p => category == null || category == p.category);
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Product {
    return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
  }

  getCategories(): string[] {
    return this.categories;
  }
}
```

Here's `product.model.ts`:

```js
export class Product {

  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public category?: string,
    public description?: string,
    public price?: number
  ) { }
}
```

That threw another error:

`Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`

Is the error on line 22 due to an error in the `Product` class? What's the error in the `Product` class? It looks like the class has a constructor.

I went to the book's GitHub repo and downloaded the latest files, which are the same as in the book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't understand the value in telling someone that is obviously learning 'just turn off strict mode' because if you are learning Angular and Typescript today then strict type checking is a reality and a really good thing. It is there to better optimize builds. Also, there are linting rules that prevent the use of the null assertion operator to help you write better code that can be optimized. The book is for Angular 9 which used an older version of Typescript and neither of them enforced strict type checking to the level they do today.

This code is not throwing errors because strict mode is enabled - it is throwing errors because things are not typed correctly anymore. This code was okay in Angular 9 but it will throw errors in newer versions. I have also been running into these issues when upgrading older projects to Angular 10 and 11 and I haven't resorted to turning off strict mode - I fixed the code to make it better.

This error:

```
Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
```

is not because strict mode is turned on, it is because JavaScript Array methods return `undefined` if an index is not defined. So this line

```
return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
```

can either return a `Product` or `undefined` if a Product with that id doesn't exist. You need to understand that and handle it.

This error

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

is because `null` is a type in TypeScript. You need to type this correctly.

```
getProducts(category: string = null): Product[] {
```

should be changed to

```
getProducts(category: string | null = null): Product[] {
```

I am sorry if this sounds like a rant because it isn't. When I answer questions on stackoverflow I try to teach to give a better understanding of the underlying issues.

Comment: Three good answers in one hour! Thanks StackOverflow! I guessed that these were strict mode problems as there were earlier errors that I was able to fix. I agree that I would like to learn "strict" TypeScript. I'll fix the errors that I can but some of these are beyond me and I'll have to switch off strict mode.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot going on here, I'll try to explain step by step :

Firstly, it looks like you have `'strict'` mode turned on in Angular. Now, because you are following a book, I recommend you turn it off because it basically enables strict typing and some other stuff like that. It is in general a good practice in an actual project so you can avoid any possible mistakes but here you can safely disable it. To disable it, within the `tsconfig.json` set the `strict` key to `false`.

> Error: src/app/model/product.repository.ts:13:7 - error TS2322: Type
> '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.   Type
> 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Once you turn off strict mode, the above shouldn't be a problem anymore. What the TS Compiler basically says here is that you are assigning `[]` to  a `string[]` i.e the array should contain string values, however in this case you are just initializing it to an empty array so it throws an error. This is just how strict mode works. In case you want to have strict mode turned on but resolve this, you can use the Non-null assertion operator `!` to tell the TS Compiler that `[]` is not null or undefined. Like below:

```
private categories: string[] = []!;
```

The below code will also stop throwing an error once you disable the strict mode. It is basically sort of a chained error stemming from the above initialization and strict mode itself.

**To explain how the code works below:**
This code is using ES6+ Arrow syntax. What is happening is that you're using the `Array.prototype.map()` function in order to iterate through the `data` array that is retrieved from the `getProducts()` method and mapping the `category` property of each object from the `data` array to a new array, and then on that new array, you are basically using the `Array.prototype.filter()` function and filtering the elements on the condition the index of each element is index which it will be and then calling `Array.prototype.sort()` function on it. Then storing the entire result into the `categories` property of the instance of the class.

```
this.products = data;
this.categories = data.map(p => p.category).filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
```

Finally, the below code is also throwing an error due to 'strict' mode being enabled:

```
return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
```

**And, to answer the below question:**

> In JavaScript I would make an empty string: var myString = ''. In
> TypeScript why would you make a string null? Aren't string and null
> different types?

string is a primitive type, therefore you can assign null to it. Both in the case of JS or TS to be honest. The reason you were not able to assign null is again because of strict mode. If you ever have strict mode turned on and still want to assign a null or undefined value as an initializaition, you can just use the non-null assertion operator `!` like below:

```
const myString: string = null!;
```

Comment: I guessed that these were strict mode problems because there had been other errors that I'd fixed earlier in the book. For these errors I tried switching off strict mode in angular.json but that didn't do it. (There's a strict mode setting there too.) Thanks for pointing me to tsconfig.json.

Comment: After I switched off "strict" mode and got rid of these three errors another error appeared in another file. After several hours of bug hunting I've figured out that switching off "strict" mode isn't a single line. Here's how to do it. In ```tsconfig.json```, change four lines to ```false```: strict, strictInjectionParameters, strictInputAccessModifiers, and strictTemplates.

Comment: The remaining 3 lines from inside of `angularCompilerOptions` are basically for the `Angular Compiler` and not the `Typescript` compiler itself. Angular apps have 2 compilers, one that compiles the `Typescript code` and another that compiles the `Angular Templates (component.html files)`. So, in case you are displaying something that might be null or undefined on the template using a directive or interpolation, you will need to use the non-null assertion operator `!` or turn off the `Angular Compiler's` strict mode setting those 3 options to false.

Comment: In short, Angular has four "strict" modes, not one.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

- Learn about [strict null checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks).
- What follows, use same compiler settings as the textbook you follow
- Please post one question at a time

**Strict null checks**

Compare:

```
var x: string | undefined;
var y: string = x;

console.log(y);
```

- With strict null checks disabled, it compiles and prints undefined.
- With strict null checks enabled, it does not compile with error message:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Note that `--strictNullChecks` can also be defined in tsconfig
either with [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) or with [strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) flag (the latter grouping all strict options under one flag).

**Where does the undefined come from?**

You have an optional property in `Product` class.

```
public category?: string
```

```
this.categories = 
  data.map(p => p.category)       // this is (string | undefined)[]
      .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index)
      .sort();
```

What does this code do?
It takes products, maps them to categories, and removes the duplicates.

**Other errors**

Other errors fall into the same category:
strict null check enabled vs strict null check disabled error.

```
getProducts(category: string = null): Product[] {
}
// Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

and

```
return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
// Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
//  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
```

Comment: All three questions had one answer: switch off strict mode. Sometimes three errors are easier to debug than one error because you can see what's common between the three errors.